# How to print out equations in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, typesetting, mathematical-typesetting

How do I define that a formula should not be computed, but rather displayed in Traditional format? Here are 2 examples, where the first one is displayed like I want it, but the second one is simplified.

```
Print["5. ", Limit[f[x]/g[x], x -> a], "=", Limit[f[x], x -> a]/Limit[g[x], x -> a], ", where ", Limit[g[x], x -> a] != 0];
Print["7. ", Limit[c, x -> a], "=", c]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [HoldForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldForm.html) to print an expression without evaluating it.

```
Print["7. ", HoldForm[Limit[c, x -> a]], "=", c]
(* /*        ^^^^^^^^                      */ *)
```

Comment: Might want to add 'TraditionalForm` to print the way Margus requested

Answer (score 5):

It depends a little bit on exactly what you want to do, but if you're just writing text, don't use `Print`.  Instead, enter the text directly, making sure you are using a `Text` cell and not an `Input` cell. In the menu, select:

```
Format -> Style -> Text
```

Then type out what you want, like:

```
5. Limit[f[x]/g[x], x -> a] == Limit[f[x], x->a]/Limit[g[x], x -> a] where ...
```

Select the expression you want to convert to `TraditionalForm` and then in the menu again, select:

```
Cell -> ConvertTo -> TraditionalForm
```

... and you should get something like this:

[image]

You might also find the screencast on typesetting useful:
[http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/screencasts/howtoentermathematicaltypesetting/](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/screencasts/howtoentermathematicaltypesetting/?w=800&h=600)

If you're actually trying to produce TraditionalForm output programmatically (e.g., with `Print`) you might consider using `Row` and `TraditionalForm` with `HoldForm`:

```
Print[Row[{
   "5. ",
    TraditionalForm[HoldForm[
     Limit[f[x]/g[x], x -> a] == Limit[f[x], x -> a]/Limit[g[x], x -> a]]],
   " where ..."
   }]]
```

Comment: This workshop from the 2011 Wolfram Tech Conference might be useful too: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8010/

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand you correctly -- you don't want Limit[c, x -> a] to be evaluated.
Standart way to stop something from evaluation is to use "Hold".

```
  Print["7. ", Hold[Limit[c, x -> a]], "=", c]
```

But the result is not good:

```
  7. Hold[Limit[c, x -> a]] = c
```

The HoldForm command does the trick -- it holds evaluation but doesn't show up:

```
  Print["7. ", HoldForm[Limit[c, x -> a]], "=", c]
  7. Limit[c, x -> a] = c
```